# How to set a property with the webapp root in Spring?

Tags: spring, servlets, configuration

Maybe the title is a little bit obscure, but let me explain... In a servlet, to know the webapp root, you'll do:

```
String path = getServletContext.getRealPath("/");
```

the problem is that you have to be in a servlet. Now I'd like to pass this path to a generic bean, that is wired up in my servlet-context.xml . How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bean can request to be injected with the current `ServletContext`, either by implementing the `ServletContextAware` interface, or else using autowiring, i.e.

```
private @Autowired ServletContext servletContext;
```

Use whichever one fits your code & config best.

You might also to consider using Spring's `ServletContextResource` class to perform filesystem access against the `ServletContext`, e.g. using `ServletContextResource.getFile()`.